# What is the counterexample for "The sequence {$d(x_n,y_n)$} converges as $n\rightarrow\infty$ only if $X$ is complete."?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Let ($X,d$) be a metric space and let  $<x_n>$ and $<y_n>$ be  arbitrary Cauchy sequences in $X$.Which of the following statement is true?

a.The sequence {$d(x_n,y_n)$} converges as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

b.The sequence {$d(x_n,y_n)$} converges as $n\rightarrow\infty$ only if $X$ is complete.

Solution:
[the proof for part (a) is same as amsmath's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2467462/let-x-d-be-a-metric-space-and-letx-nand-y-nbe-arbitrary-sequences)

**What is the counterexample for (b) part?**

Comment: If you're looking for a counterexample, come up with a metric space $X$ that is not complete and see if you can prove that $\{d(x_n, y_n)\}$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$ for arbitrary Cauchy sequences $x_n,y_n$.

Comment: @@Neal: I think part (a) has already told us about the  convergence of {$d(x_n,y_n)$} in an arbitrary space $X$, so the notion of " completeness" become meaningless.

Comment: All the answers seem to be counterexamples for part a), but the OP is asking for a counterexample for part b), which could be for example a constant sequence in $\mathbb{Q}.$  Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @saulspatz:  as the part is about the arbitrary metric space while the provided answers are in respect to a specific metric space, so the answers  below are not counterexamples for part (a)

Comment: @PKStyles I don't understand.  The statements supposed to be true for every metric space $X$ so a single counterexample proves the statement false.

Comment: @saulspatz $d(x_n, y_n)$ are naturally elements of $\mathbb R$, not $X$, so in context the space in which the $d(x_n, y_n)$ are supposed to converge is also $\mathbb R$, not $X$. None of the answers disprove that.

Answer (score 6):

Get $\mathbb{Q}$ with the Euclidean distance. Then if $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are arbitrary Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$, they are also Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{R}$, so by the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ they have limit in $\mathbb{R}$, say to $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and to $y\in\mathbb{R}$ respectively. So:
$$d(x_n,y_n)=|x_n-y_n|\rightarrow|x-y|, n\rightarrow\infty.$$
On the other hand, $\mathbb{Q}$ with the Euclidean distance is not a complete metric space, because for example the truncated decimal expansion of $\sqrt2$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ that doesn't admit limit in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 2):

For an extremely simple counterexample, let $(X,d)=( (0,1), |\cdot|)$ Let $x_n=\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $y_n=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$. Then $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are Cauchy sequences in $(0,1)$ that do not converge in $(0,1)$, meaning that $(0,1)$ is not complete. But:

$$|x_n-y_n|=\left|1-\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right|=\left|1-\frac{2}{n+1}\right|\rightarrow 1\ as\ n\rightarrow\infty$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread this ☹️; it's a fine answer. Unfortunately the vote's locked in until there's an edit. So – would it be alright with you to remove the first paragraph? I think the question asker had already realized that (b) must be wrong due to (a) being true, and was specifically asking for a counterexample.

Comment: Oh okay, it happens from time to time haha. I made an edit :)

Comment: Cheers. And apologies again.

Answer (score -3):

Take

$$X=\Bbb Q$$
$$d=| \;\; |$$

$$x_n=1+\frac 11 +\frac{1}{2!}+...+\frac{1}{n!}$$

$$y_n=2x_n$$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}|y_n-x_n|=e\notin \Bbb Q$$

$(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are Cauchy in $\Bbb Q$ but the differene $(y_n-x_n)$ is not convergent in $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Can you give a reason for these downvotes.

Comment: When the question says $d(x_n, y_n)$ converges, it means it converges in $\mathbb R$, not $X$. In general $d(x_n,y_n)$ isn't even an element of $X$.